# dynamically add arguments ,arguments types and argument values to a method in JAVA/ANDROID

Tags: java, android

How can I dynamically add argument,argument types and argument values to a method in java.

Given below is an example of a testcase method name **testBlockTest104** .Similarly there are 1000 of tescases .I can fetch the method name at runtime using reflection but not getting a way to dynamically add the arguments , argument types and argument values.
My purpose is to run around thousands of test case differing in the method names and the argument types and their values based on the number and type of arguments.

Basically Passing variable arguments numbers ,types in getMethod() and values in .invoke() method.

```
 String methodName = "testBlockTest104";


 try {
       Method m  = testBlock.getClass().getMethod(methodName, testParam1.unit1.class, testParam2.unit2.class,resultcallback.result.class);

 try {
          m.invoke(testBlock, unit1_value, unit2_value,resultcallback_val);
      }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      Log.i("Exception=> " + ex.getMessage());
   }
 } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                Log.i("Exception=> " + e1.getMessage());
   }
 catch (NoSuchMethodException e2) {
   Log.i("Exception=> " + e2.getMessage());
    }
```

I have got success in calling a method using the  reflection (by reading the method name from the text file ) .But i want to achieve this.

```
Purpose 1:
```

This is part of one Test Engine framework provided to the tester in the form of the binary(exe/apk) where the type of testcases can be supplied by the tester(in an xml format . tester has no knowledge of the code ) The xml will be parsed by the test engine(code above) and methods will be derived based on it.

e.g XML below :

```
<test-id-103>
<method-name>
  <method-params>

  </method-params>

  <method-types>

</method-types>
<method-values>
</method-values>
</method-name>
</test-id-103>




 Purpose 2:
```

Ok so the purpose above may not seems reasonable to some so I am jotting down another purpose of this approach .Though more on the project management side and less on technical.The developer writing this test engine will be leaving the company and the static test cases he will be writing (if not this approach) will be like writing test-case with fixed hard coded values which can never be changed once he is gone.So by the above approach the tester can pass any values , any arguments he likes to a given test case so there is no dependency on the Developer's code.The whole XML will be parsed into one big buffer which will be parsed at the time of running the test cases ( I dont think this will take much time).More over the testcases can be customized by editing a simple xml file.This is just a top level view of the purpose I mentioned.

Comment: Exactly what value are you getting out of this?  If you want to call foo(x,y), call foo(x,y).  There's no value in wrapping it in reflection and invokes like this.

Comment: @GabeSechan added the purpose !

Comment: ...ugh.  I'd quit rather than work with a system like that.

Comment: well its a personnel choice !

Answer (score 1):

ANy parameter that takes a variadic argument (like getMethod) can be passed an array instead.  So you can create a Class[], put all the parameter Class objects into it, and pass it to getMethod instead.  Same for invoke.

Although I really think you ought to just rethink this approach.  You're making your tests slower and more complicated with this xml based approach with no real benefit.  Its not even like you can pass it off to a non-programmer to write tests, as the user would still need to know enough programming to know what the functions were and what the parameters are.  All you'll be doing is slowing your organization down as running the test suite will take 10x the time it would normally.

Comment: i appreciate your thought ,Updated the question with the reason why I want to do this

Comment: I am trying this.. will update more on my attempt. Thanks gor the answer !